# Gitlab master repository to our production server via ssh ?

Tags: git, cron, gitlab

How can I connect GitLab master repository to our production server via SSH ? 
If someone can put some reference ? 
I have found already this: 
https://about.gitlab.com/2016/05/10/feature-highlight-push-to-remote-repository/ 
But I can't find it in our gitlab repository ?

Comment: You would normally configure your production server to *pull* from your gitlab repository.

Comment: Hm, or that way. 
But do you have any reference anywhere on the net ?

Answer (score 0):

https://mikeeverhart.net/2013/01/using-git-to-deploy-code/ - this is what I have invested sometime to and now it works. Thanks to the larsks comment.